# I'm trying to use a simple webcam capture upload, upload isn't working?

Tags: javascript, php, html, upload

UPDATE:

This is the entire code, which I pretty much copied and pasted.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript"></script>

<style>

</style>
</head>
<body>
<script>
Webcam.set({
    width: 320,
    height: 240,
    dest_width: 640,
    dest_height: 480,
    image_format: 'jpeg',
    jpeg_quality: 90,
    force_flash: false
});
</script>
<div id="web_camera" style="width:320px; height:240px;"></div>
<div id="cam_result"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="webcam.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript">
   document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        Webcam.set({
            width: 320,
            height: 240,
            image_format: 'jpeg',
            jpeg_quality: 90
        });
        Webcam.attach( '#web_camera' );
        function take_snapshot() {
            // take snapshot and get image data
            Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
                // display results in page
                document.getElementById('cam_results').innerHTML =
                    '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' +
                    '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
                                Webcam.upload( data_uri, 'upload.php', function(code, text) {
                                            // Upload complete!
                                            // 'code' will be the HTTP response code from the server, e.g. 200
                                            // 'text' will be the raw response content
                                });
            } );
        }
   });
  </script>
<a href="javascript:void(take_snapshot())">Take Snapshot</a>

</body>
```

I'm using this link

http://mycodingtricks.com/javascript/webcam-api/

This one looks a lot better but may be the same thing

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/getusermedia/intro/

What I'm concerned about is the data_uri, also the url upload

So the webcam works, shows my face, whatever, but I push this

```
<a href="javascript:void(take_snapshot())">Take Snapshot</a>
```

and nothing happens. I see the little grey box at the bottom left saying javascript:void(take_snapshot()) I'm wondering if I'm supposed to put a parameter...

There can be several problems, I am using domain mapping and the folder may be pointed incorrectly or it could be a file permission problem, I did chown with www-data

This is the upload.php as suggested or rather given by the first link

```
<?php
    // be aware of file / directory permissions on your server
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['webcam']['tmp_name'], '/tabdater/uploads/webcam'.md5(time()).rand(383,1000).'.jpg');
?>
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors and are you running this on a server or running it locally?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "... the console..." and I am running it on a server, the webpage is live, testing it on a tablet.

Comment: can you post more of the code you're using so i can look further into this issue or post a link to your testing page, thanks.

Comment: I posted the whole code of the page. I'm having a problem with the upload linking eg. actually working. Thanks for your time. The upload.php file is shown above very basic / un-modified.

Comment: Can you tell me what is/isn't working? When the page loads can you see the webcam stream? If you don't see the webcam stream then you may find this error in the console "Uncaught ReferenceError: Webcam is not defined" and this would be due to not having webcams.js uploaded or in the correct directory. If you have this online it would be much easier to give me a link and i can make sure you have all the required files since this isn't your project, i have a copy of this and all seems to be working for me.

Comment: The stream works, for my tablet Windows 8.1 VivoTab8, but it doesn't work on an iPhone which is another problem entirely. What isn't working is the saving of a screen shot and file upload.

Comment: The project is mine, except the code which I literally copied and pasted with some minor modification but this is the site, it is far from finished. I am not developing locally because I don't have php/apache/sql locally installed (it was a pain last time) so I develop live online, I realize it's bad but I sort of pray that no one knows about my site yet until I start to advertise it. This is the page which loads the camera fine it's the saving and file upload that isn't working. tabdater.com/camera2.html

Comment: Looking at the url in the comment above, you don't have a function called take_snapshot so that would be why the application isn't taking the snapshot. Once you have the snapshot displaying you will want to use ajax to post that image to your PHP, once you manage to pass that image to PHP it will be encoded (base64) so you will need to decode the base64 before saving the image. Can you paste what you have so far into codepen or something so i can see how far you are, then i can help you get closer to finishing your application. :)

Comment: I'm not anywhere, yet, what you see is what I currently have. I'm currently doing the php sign up parameter binding, password hashing stuff, but I will be getting to this today and hopefully solving this today with your help. The link made it so simple like everything was already there. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This should be a great starting point for you. I hope this helps you.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Cam Snap</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="webcam.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
function take_snapshot() {
    Webcam.snap(function(data_uri) {
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = '<img id="base64image" src="'+data_uri+'"/><button onclick="SaveSnap();">Save Snap</button>';
});
}
function ShowCam(){
Webcam.set({
width: 320,
height: 240,
image_format: 'jpeg',
jpeg_quality: 100
});
Webcam.attach('#my_camera');
}
function SaveSnap(){
    document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML="Saving, please wait...";
    var file =  document.getElementById("base64image").src;
    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("base64image", file);
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    ajax.addEventListener("load", function(event) { uploadcomplete(event);}, false);
    ajax.open("POST", "upload.php");
    ajax.send(formdata);
}
function uploadcomplete(event){
    document.getElementById("loading").innerHTML="";
    var image_return=event.target.responseText;
    var showup=document.getElementById("uploaded").src=image_return;
}
window.onload= ShowCam;
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.container{display:inline-block;width:320px;}
#Cam{background:rgb(255,255,215);}#Prev{background:rgb(255,255,155);}#Saved{background:rgb(255,255,55);}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" id="Cam"><b>Webcam Preview...</b>
    <div id="my_camera"></div><form><input type="button" value="Snap It" onClick="take_snapshot()"></form>
</div>
<div class="container" id="Prev">
    <b>Snap Preview...</b><div id="results"></div>
</div>
<div class="container" id="Saved">
    <b>Saved</b><span id="loading"></span><img id="uploaded" src=""/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP (Must have the uploads directory) -

```
<?php
define('UPLOAD_DIR', 'uploads/');
$img = $_POST['base64image'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/jpeg;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
print $success ? $file : 'Unable to save the file.';
?>
```

Credit to [This Blog](http://j-query.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/save-base64-encoded-canvas-image-to-png.html) for the php!

Comment: I'm going to try this out and see what you have written, more than likely this is exactly what I need and will award you best answer. That's kind of weak, depending on what happens with the project I'll contact you but don't hold your breath haha on its success. Anyway thank you very much for your help. I'll get back to you in an hour or so to check out and try out your code.

Comment: No problem, if you have any problems understand the answer just let me know and will will edit the answer and add comments for you.

Comment: Thanks again I'm about to get to this in a few minutes.

Comment: Curious if you considered file upload safety, I have some stuff written by someone else on file upload "scanning" omg man! Thank you so much. I'm going to credit you and this link in the about page of tabdater haha.

Comment: Oh yes I do have a question about compatibility, have you looked into iphone/safari concerning this, I haven't tested if it works on iphone yet my friend has one and he's not here.

Comment: I always leave room for improvement as it's the point of learning from the answer, i'm glad you're happy with this and it's good to hear helps. I wish you the very best with your project/website.

Comment: I have checked this with an android tablet, all seem to work well but as far as apple/safari goes I don't think this will work.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what triggers the front camera? It seems to always use the front camera by default. I am wondering about switching front and back.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, it could be using the devices default/primary camera.

Answer (score 0):

Its not working because you had included the `take_snapshot()` function in `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {` function.

Please follow the tutorial...

You code should look like:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Webcam Demo - <MyCodingTricks/></title>
<link href="http://mycodingtricks.com/demo/style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
<body>
 <h3>Demonstrates simple 320x240 capture &amp; display</h3>
 <div id="my_camera"></div>
 <!-- A button for taking snaps -->
 <form>
  <input type=button class="btn btn-success" value="Take Snapshot" onClick="take_snapshot()">
 </form>
 <div id="results" class="well">Your captured image will appear here...</div>
<script src="http://mycodingtricks.com/demo/script.js"></script>

 <!-- First, include the Webcam.js JavaScript Library -->
 <script type="text/javascript" src="webcam.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Configure a few settings and attach camera -->
 <script language="JavaScript">
  Webcam.set({
   width: 320,
   height: 240,
   image_format: 'jpeg',
   jpeg_quality: 90
  });
  Webcam.attach( '#my_camera' );
  function take_snapshot() {
   // take snapshot and get image data
   Webcam.snap( function(data_uri) {
    // display results in page
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = 
     '<h2>Here is your image:</h2>' + 
     '<img src="'+data_uri+'"/>';
                                Webcam.upload( data_uri, 'upload.php', function(code, text) {
                                            // Upload complete!
                                            // 'code' will be the HTTP response code from the server, e.g. 200
                                            // 'text' will be the raw response content
                                });
   } );
  }
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Doesn't work ! Nothing happens when the button is clicked !